# Querying Array concept in Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

How to write a query for an attribute in the array concept. 
Example: fetch the address based on city attribute.

```
namespace org.sample.basic

participant User identified by userId{
    o String userId
    o Address[] address optional

}

concept Address {
    o String address1
    o String address2
    o String city
    o String state
    o Integer zipcode
    o String country 
    o Boolean isAddressValidated default = false 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

given data of:

```
{ "$class": "org.sample.basic.User", "userId": "id1", "address": [ { $class": "org.sample.basic.Address", "address1": "the-vines", "city": "newyork" }, { $class": "org.sample.basic.Address", "address1": "the-gables", "city": "dallas" } ] }  // and so on
```

your querydef (not posted all fields FYI) would be :

```
query myquery { 
  description: "Select all x" statement: 
   SELECT org.sample.basic.User 
  WHERE (address CONTAINS (city == "dallas") OR (city == "newyork") ) 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope you're using Hyperledger Query Language. Can you try something like this ?

```
SELECT org.sample.basic.User  
      WHERE ( address CONTAINS (city== _$city) )
```

Comment: It works if it is a single address. I need for an array of address.

Comment: Can you explain your scenario please?

 address is User node is array of address right? `CONTAINS` [defines conditions for array values](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/query-language) .